# Detect when optimal location accuracy is reached with CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I'm currently working on an app that uses CLLocationManager with the lowest accuracy (kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers). However, once every couple minutes I need to get an accurate location of the user, so I set the accuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyBest when a timer expires.

Obviously, CLLocationManager starts updating the location, going from an inaccurate location to more accurate locations in steps. The problem is, however, that I don't know how to detect when the optimal location accuracy has been reached, so I never know when I have the best location to work with.

Does anybody know a solution to this problem? It would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IN the [`CLLocationManagerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html) method [`locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidUpdateLocations%3a) look at the [`horizontalAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW5) of [`CLLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html). This will give you the radius in meters.

As stated in documentation:

> The radius of uncertainty for the location, measured in meters.
>   (read-only)

The location manager will keep trying in getting the best accuracy as possible, so you will have to decide when the location is accurate enough.

Answer (score 2):

Similar functionality is implemented in detail by Apple in the sample project "LocateMe". Check out GetLocationViewController from LocateMe here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/locateme.